# Can I use Phonegap initially and then just use Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I'm very new to the mobile app development section. I'm confused between Cordova and Phonegap. So far what I've seen is Phonegap seems like an extension?(of Cordova). So I was wondering if I could develop/code my app using phonegap initially(since with phonegap I can view it in my mobile) and finally during building the apk/ipa if I could build it just using cordova/node?

Initially I decided to just use phonegap but one of my supervisors advised me to use cordova since phonegap is less frequently updated than cordova and also because phonegap allows only 1 app build for free at the moment.

Correct me where im wrong and also provide all the information you guys can, I'm a real noob in this topic.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap uses Cordova internally, so if you are going to develop locally you can continue using Phonegap as it has the desktop app and developer app that help you testing the app easily. Apps generated by Phonegap are Cordova apps. If you don't need any of the Phonegap features, then use Cordova.

Right now both Cordova and Phonegap are in version 8.0.0, so it's almost the same.

The only difference is, when the next Cordova version is released, you'll have to wait a few weeks/months until Phonegap catch up. In that case might make sense to use Cordova instead to take advantage of the new features/bug fixes earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a project with phonegap and then use it with cordova CLI.

I've seen problems when going the other way : making a project with cordova and then using it with phonegap build but even then it was just a namespace to change in config.xml.

I'm not sure phonegap is updated less frequently, I'd rather say that when there is a new version of cordova, the new version of phonegap may arrive few days later.

For differences between cordova and phonegap, you can have a look at [this page from phonegap](https://phonegap.com/products/).

When you say

> since with phonegap I can view it in my mobile

you're talking about [the phonegap developer app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.phonegap.app)?

Answer (score 0):

I can see how this can be confusing. If you go and read on this page (https://phonegap.com/products/) you'll find something like this

> Apache Cordova was born from PhoneGap...

but then, they say

> The PhoneGap CLI is the most powerful and flexible way to use PhoneGap. Built on top of Apache Cordova, you can create, serve, compile, and run apps from the comfort of your command-line terminal...

Confusing, of course..., how can PhoneGap be built on top of Cordova if Cordova was born from PhoneGap?

Here is what happened

- first it was just PhoneGap (the software) made by Nitobi (the company)
- in 2011 Adobe purchased Nitobi and re-branded it as PhoneGap
- later Adobe released an open source version of the PhoneGap software called Apache Cordova

So, now we have the open source software named Cordova (formerly named PhoneGap), but we also have Adobe's PhoneGap (the brand, the software (CLI, App, Desktop) and the cloud build services).

If you go with Cordova, you can make apps using HTML, CSS and JavaScript but to build them requires (depends on) the platform specific SDKs (from Google, Apple and Microsoft) installed on your computer.

PhoneGap gives you 3 options, read more here (http://docs.phonegap.com/references/phonegap-cli/install/), including the cloud PhoneGap Build service, which saves you from the need of installing platform specific SDKs on your computer.

---

I hope this helps.